# Flutter - ping google.com and get the latency in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Anyone know how to ping google and get latency in Flutter? I am using dart_ping but fail to ping.

Answer (score 0):

Try dart_ping:

**Setup:**

```
dependencies:
  dart_ping: ^1.0.0
```

**Notes:**

- Watch the spacing. It should be excatly correct in the pubspec.yaml . You can add the second line (dart_ping: ^1.0.0) right below cupertino_icons: ^....
- Remember to click on Packages Get (in Android Studio).

**Usage:**

```
import 'package:dart_ping/dart_ping.dart';

main() async {
  var stream = await ping("google.com", times: 5);

  print("Pinging google.com");
  stream.listen((d) {
    print(d.time.inMilliseconds);
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi @Yster, thx for helping me. For some reason my d.time.inMilliseconds just refuse to print out. The main() function should I include in Widget build(BuildContext context ){} or outside?

Comment: I see what you mean....it doesn't work! It should work just like that in a dart file. stream is not null. Nothing is received. Sorry about this. I tried to report the bug, but they don't seem to have a github project. Can only look into this further in 1 month. Hope you can find another solution.

Comment: No problem, thanks for replying me again. Hope it will be fixed soon.